# Getting better text rendering quality in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, text-rendering

Is there a way I could get a better text rendering quality in window forms.

I tried playing with the "TextRenderingHint", but was of no use.

The font is Helvetica Neue LT Pro, and the desired outcome created in photoshop appears on the left of the attached image. I introduced it in .NET using the .otf file as a resource.

[image]

Comment: What control are you putting the image onto?

Comment: this is a button control, and I don't wanna put an image on the control, I want to render normal text. Images are always possible, but hardly maintained

Comment: Is your "Helvetica Neue LT Pro" font a photoshop specific font or a built in windows font? does this font exist on you end machine were you program will be installed?
You must make sure that your button is not falling back to some other font because your Helvetica font might not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Winforms doesn't support Open Type fonts.  So the Windows font mapper found you a substitute TrueType font.  It resembles your original font but of course doesn't render the same.  Not having ClearType enabled won't improve the outcome either.

Open Type font support in Windows in general is not exactly stellar.  You can typically only rely on Adobe programs to support it well, there's no decent fallback for programs that render text with GDI or GDI+.  I only know of WPF as a GUI builder tool that support it.  Dealing with the gratuitous Adobe product compatibility problems on Windows has a long, long history.  And resembles the joy I experience having to use Flash or Reader.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would first be to make your image the exact size you require the button to be incorporating the required margin. Then `TextImageRelation = ImageAboveText`, `ImageAlign = MiddleCenter`, `AutoSize = True` and `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`.

This is about all you can do apart from switching to WPF and living happily ever after with your amazing WPF buttons.

I hope this helps.